# Dynamically added menu items disappear on click in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

I followed the [Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) to create a navigation drawer.

Then I wanted to add 2 groups of menu items. One for user created lists, the other for labels. Since I couldn't directly set titles to groups, I followed the tutorial [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542903/4673960) and wrapped groups in  tags.

My XML menu looks like this: [image: XML Menu]

In onCreate I find the NavigationView using its id, then get its menu, get the first  by its id, get the item's SubMenu and add MenuItems:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu menu =  navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item_lists);
SubMenu sbLists = item.getSubMenu();
sbLists.add(0, 0, 0, "Android").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_android);
sbLists.add(0, 1, 0, "iOS").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ios);
```

And:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    menuItem -> {
        // set item as selected to persist highlight
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // close drawer when item is tapped
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

When I click the items added in XML, the drawer closes and if I open it again I can see the item is selected. 
However, with the items added in onCreate, this is what I see after I re-open the drawer:

Clicking this one
[image: Before click]

It's gone
[image: After]

I've tried searching on Stack Overflow and found only one question with the same problem [Navigation item's title disappeared when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989663/navigation-items-title-disappeared-when-clicked) , however, the solution is to set the item text color to black. That doesn't fix the item not being selected problem and  doesn't fix the icon disappearing either.

Please let me know what I'm doing incorrectly, thank you!

Edit:
Here's what my Theme looks like in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="iconColor">@color/icons_light</item>
    <item name="toolbarIconColor">@color/icons_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It looks disabled, not gone.

Comment: Is it disabled? Is it clickable or not?

Comment: @forpas It is not disabled. I can click it, but nothing shows. If I follow the solution to a similar problem (linked above) then I can see the text.

Comment: Maybe it needs to set the TextColor of the item when you create and add the item to the Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Even though I had declared `android:checkableBehavior="single">` in XML for the group I was adding items to, I still had to manually do `setCheckable(true)` for each item added programatically.

```
subMenu.add(R.id.group_lists, ITEM_ID, ITEM_ORDER, "item").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_list).setCheckable(true);
```

Now, when I click an item created in either XML or Java, both the icon and the text are visible, the item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the theme of your `NavigationView` set the `colorPrimary` and for the text and `colorControlHighlight` for the selected background element :

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.myTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color-primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color-primary</item>
</style>
```

and set it in your `NavigationView` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.myTheme">
```

Comment: The XML items, when selected, lose their icon and text and are filled by the colorPrimary. And I still cannot select items added in Java: Here's a video of how that looks: https://youtu.be/m0ODuheNik8

Comment: it's because the theme you are using

Comment: Okay, I've added the theme at the bottom of my question. What should I modify to get this up and running?

Comment: I replied because I tried your solution. I also provided a video showing the effects of your solution. Answer - it did not work, unfortunately.